# Specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found for a Linux Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, .net-core-3.1

## Problem

After upgrading a .Net Core 2.2 Linux Web App to .Net Core 3.1 in Azure, the application is down with a `Specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found` error.  I even went as far to create a new Linux Web App with .Net Core 3.1, and after the bash command prompt is still outputting `dotnet --list-runtimes` as `2.2.7`.

## Details

**Website Down**

[image: Application Error]

**Logstream**

reporting application is down because it can't find .net core 3.1.

[image: Logstream]

**Created new .net core web app**

3.1 linux webapp in North Central, same problem

[image: Created new web app]

**Ensured it was running in North Central US**

According to https://aspnetcoreon.azurewebsites.net/, should have full .netCore 3.1 support

**Still .net core 2.2.7**
[image: cmd prompt 2.2.7]

**`opt/dotnet/runtimes` lists 3, 3.0 and 3.0.0, but no 3.1`**
[image]

**Environment variables**

My environment variables in Azure list `FRAMEWORK_VERSION = lts`, instead of 3.1

**Publishing**

This was published from an azure devops ci pipeline using an Azure AppService Deploy task.  3.1 wasn't available here, so I chose `LTS`

[image: Devops release pipeline]

## Update 1

It seems the culprit is 3.1 missing from the framework stack in Azure Devops Web App / Web Service tasks.

Whenever I publish from CI, the web app framework is updated to whatever is selected in this dropdown.  If I manually go change the framework to 3.1 on the Azure Web App, the site comes up.  But then the next publish it goes back down because it reverts the framework back to the settings in the ci.

**New Question**

How can I get the Azure Devops Release pipeline to publish a .net core 3.1 task?

## Update 2

**Related Azure Devops forum post**

Currently being investigated as of 2/23/2020

[.Net Core 3.1 deploy pipeline to Linux App Service](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/868129/net-core-31-deploy-pipeline-to-linux-app-service.html)

**Suggested Workarounds**

1. Use YML for release pipeline and manually change the version from `3.0` to `3.1`, noted by answer and [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/855678/view.html)
2. Upgrade from a `framework dependent` release to a `self contained`. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#deploy-aspnet-core-preview-release-to-azure-app-service)
3. Downgrade to .NetCore 3.0

Comment: Instead of using LTS please try using latest (its not recommended but try it anyway, will see whether its working or not)

Comment: I did, and it didn't work.  But CI seems to be the problem. Every time I publish with CI it changes the framework on the web app to whatever is selected in CI. If I go to the app service after a CI publish and manually change the runtime stack to 3.1, the site comes up until the next publish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into the same situation, using the information you provided I've been able to fix the issue by setting the value manually in the Devops Pipelines Build .yml file. It seems like they are just missing the value from RunTime Stack drop down. If you manually update the build processes .yml file as seen here:

[image]

This will select the proper framework version. Hopefully this will fix your issue with the Azure Devops CI Pipeline deployment.

Comment: I wondered if this would resolve it. I'll try giving it a shot. It might be a little bit of work for me to convert my entire release to yml so I hadn't tried it yet. I'll let you know the results! Appreciate the response!!

Comment: Seems it is possible to enter the string DOTNETCORE|3.1 directly into the Runtime Stack box (and it resolves the issue) - so no need to to convert the release pipeline to yaml!

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing as @rdavisau - easiest fix is to overtype the 3.1 version into the Runtime Stack box and it seems to take the value.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution is to type `DOTNETCORE|3.1` into the Runtime Stack dropdown in devops. (Thanks rdavisau!)

[image]